# check against: null vs default()?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, null

I want to check if a reference type is null.  I see two options (_settings is of reference type FooType):

```
if (_settings == default(FooType)) { ... }
```

and

```
if (_settings == null) { ... }
```

How do these two perform differently?

Comment: Use `default(T)`, it's more readable.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

There's no difference. The default value of any reference type is `null`.

MSDN's C# reference page for `default` keyword: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25tdedf5.aspx.

Comment: Well, I beg to differ: the first comparison is typesafe (or at least should be) this is what is basically wrong with null in c#, null == null is true  but the left null could be a string and the right null could be a complex object so default(string) should not be equal to default(complex object) it would be good if everyone stopped using null. https://blog.miguelbernard.com/why-null-in-csharp-is-so-bad

Comment: @Null: You're assuming that `null` values have a type. Is that really true?

Comment: null has all types and therefore none. Did you read the blog I was referring to ?

Comment: @Null: Yes, I read it, but I disagree with the idea that assignment implies inheritance. I do agree with the conclusion (even though I disagree with the arguments): enabling nullable type checking is ideal.

Comment: On that, I do agree too. I'm sorry that I could not come up with better arguments.

Answer (score 20):

Now that we don't need to pass the type to default anymore, default is preferred.

- It is just as readable
- It can be used both for value and reference types
- It can be used in generics

  if (_settings == default) { ... }

Also, after calling

```
obj = enumerable.FirstOrDefault();
```

it makes more sense to test for default after that and not for null. Otherwise it should have been FirstOrNull, but value dont have a null value but do have a default.

Answer (score 14):

There is no difference, but second one is more readable. The best place to use `default` is when you deal with generics. Common code is `return default(T);`

Comment: For `DateTime` it returns "0001-01-01T00:00:00" which is a Valid value... unlike `null` which is Invalid value.

Comment: @YoushaAleayoub the question asks about reference types and `DateTime` is not a reference type.

Comment: I think that's a matter of opinion. I use `default` (without parentheses) all over the place because I instinctively know what the default is for the types that I work with. It can mean `null` or DateTime.Min or `0` for my `int`. It would be more readable for people that don't automatically register the default value in their head. 

It can also, for example, help you do a search for all values that are assigned a default value. Instead of searching for `null`, `0`, or `Decimal.Zero`, you just search for `default`, `== default` , or even `is default`

Comment: @SaturnK it is a matter of taste and I prefer the explicit values over default keyword (python's zen: explicit is better than implicit). default keyword was introduced to be used with template types, because you can't have an explicit value there when it comes to default.

Answer (score 6):

Not different but I think

```
if (_settings == null) { ... }
```

is clearer.

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is they are not different. It only matters when you are dealing with value types.

Answer (score 3):

I would definitely go with the specific check against null. Because if the type of the `_settings` class ever changes you may run into reference issues. At minimum it would require a change to the code breaking the open/close policy.

```
if( _settings == null ) {...}
```

This IMO is safer and cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

As has been mentioned, there is no difference... but you *might* want to use `default(<type>)` anyway, to handle the cases where it's *not* a reference type. Typically this is only in generics, but it's a good habit to form for the general case.